# How Passport Strategy works behind the Scene

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I was trying to comprehend how passport strategy is working.

Consider these api routes which I am using to authenticate.

```
  router.get("/google",  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
  router.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
  })
```

And this is the passport strategy

```
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStratergy = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const keys = require("./key.js")
const User = require("../models/user-model.js")

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id) 
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user) //pass it in req of our routes
    })
})

passport.use(
    new GoogleStratergy({
    //Options for the stratergy 
        callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback", 
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {


        User.findOne({userId: profile.id }).then((currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                done(null, currentUser)
            } else {
                    //Changing Image String
                    let  oldURL=  profile.photos[0]["value"]
                    let newURL =  oldURL.substr(0,  oldURL.length-2);
                    newURL = newURL + "250"
                //Creating Mongoose Database
                    new User({
                        username: profile.displayName,
                        userId: profile.id,
                        image: newURL,
                        email: profile.emails[0]["value"]
                    }).save().then((newUser) => {
                        console.log("new user created", newUser)
                        done(null, newUser)
                   })
            }

        })

    })
)
```

Now, I think I understand what is happening here, but one thing I am unable to comprehend here is..

How is

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStratergy({
    //Options for the stratergy
```

being called here? I mean I don't see any export statements, so how is it linked with out Node App? or how does passport knows behind the scene about the location of our google strategy **

Also, Just to confirm, after we pass done from our passport.use? it goes to serialize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `require` passport, you get a singleton instance i.e. it's constructed the first time you `require` passport, and is reused every time and everywhere it's `require`d subsequently.

So you don't need to share the instance between modules i.e. no need for export. Any configuration you do on the instance is visible everywhere you require it.

There are other objects in NodeJS that work the same way, one prominent example is the `express` app instance.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/index.js) for passport where you can verify this.